# For loop in NVelocity

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, velocity, nvelocity

Does NVelocity support #for loops?
I've looked through the documentation and all I could find was the #foreach loop.

I want to loop over a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 10):

You can use range operator `[n..m]` in foreach loop to emulate normal loop. You can also access multidimensional array elements in a usual way like `$array[n][m]`.

For example if you have such 2d array (sorry for Java code):

```
String[][] testArray = new String[][] {{"a1","b1"},{"a2","b2"},{"a3","b3"}};
```

You can loop through it in Velocity like this:

```
#set($sizeX = $testArray.size() - 1)
#set($sizeY = $testArray[0].size() - 1)
#foreach($i in [0..$sizeX])
    #foreach($j in [0..$sizeY])
        e[$i][$j] = $testArray[$i][$j] <br/>
    #end
#end
```

Which outputs:

```
e[0][0] = a1
e[0][1] = b1
e[1][0] = a2
e[1][1] = b2
e[2][0] = a3
e[2][1] = b3
```

**UPDATE**:

Apparently bracketed syntax was introduced only in Velocity 1.7b1 according to changelog. In older versions we would just need to replace brackets with `get(i)` as arrays in Velocity are backed by `ArrayList` (in Java). So, this should work:

```
#set($sizeX = $testArray.size() - 1)
#set($sizeY = $testArray.get(0).size() - 1)
#foreach($i in [0..$sizeX])
    #foreach($j in [0..$sizeY])
        e[$i][$j] = $testArray.get($i).get($j) <br/>
    #end
#end
```

Comment: It isn't working.
It complains about the "[" character in you second line: "$testArray[0].size()".

And when I try to get the value of a specific array element like $testArray[1][1], it displays: System.String[][][1][1]. So apparently that syntax is not recognized.

Comment: @Mircea please see the update. All my examples are in Java, I hope NVelocity is not too different.

Comment: +1 Nice `for` loop implementation. For `C#` you should use `get_item(i)` instead of `get(i)` and `Length` instead of `size()` (or   `Count()` from linq).

Answer (score 1):

Alas, NVelocity "as is" does not support **for** loops, only **foreach**. Even [Castle Project's fork](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html) improves only foreach loop.

AFAIK, for .NET projects NVelocity is on a dead-end. We are using it in our projects, using code not unlike lonely7345 to address its shortcomings, and we kept using it because, until recently, there was no better or easier templating engine for .net.

However, we are [considering using Razor as a Standalone templating engine](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Dec/27/Hosting-the-Razor-Engine-for-Templating-in-NonWeb-Applications)...

Answer (score 0):

```
Hashtable entries = new Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
entries["listtool"] = new ListTool();
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(entries);
```

in listtool class you write your C# code to finish  the fetch 2 dimensional array.

```
public Object get(Object list, int x,int  y)
    {
         return  ((IList)list)[x][y];
    }

$listtool.get($obj,x,y);
```